# Asterisk ERROR: stasis_app_exec: Stasis app 'channel-dump' not registered

Tags: voip, asterisk

I'm testing Asterisk ARI and got this dialplan on extension 1000

```
exten => 1000,1,NoOp()
 same =>      n,Answer()
 same =>      n,Stasis(channel-dump)
 same =>      n,Wait(100)
 same =>      n,Hangup()
```

But when I call extensions 1000 I get the following error:

```
[Jun 26 16:12:45] ERROR[18152][C-00000002]: res_stasis.c:1247 stasis_app_exec: Stasis app 'channel-dump' not registered
```

Where do I need to register the application?

Answer (score 0):

Stasis is BUS

You should create asterisk application(c/c++ module) which will handle request for you.

https://wiki.asterisk.org/wiki/display/AST/Using+the+Stasis+Message+Bus